# Codeigniter Flashdata Is Not Showing

Tags: codeigniter, session, controller

i have 2 page, which contains `delete` some record, check out the first controller to delete

```
function delete($idnya)
{
            $this->m_kategorimaterial->delete($idnya);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses','Hapus kategori material berhasil');
            redirect('c_kategorimaterial');
}
```

then loaded on view

```
<div id="vkategorimaterial">
            <p><h2>Menu Kategori Material</h2></p>
        <center><notif><?php echo $this ->session->flashdata('sukses'); ?></notif></center>
```

and it works like i need. but then its not working on the other controller

```
function delete($idnya)
{
    $this->m_material->delete($idnya);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses','Hapus material berhasil');
    redirect('c_material');
}
```

and here is the views of `material`

```
<div id="vmaterial">
            <p><h2>Menu Material</h2></p>
    <center><notif><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('sukses'); ?></notif></center>
```

why does the flashdata is not showing on `material` page ? but it works on `kategorimaterial` page ? FYI, first, i make the

```
                $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses','Hapus kategori material berhasil');
```

on the `kategorimaterial` page, once it works, i copy the

```
                $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses','Hapus kategori material berhasil');
```

into `material` controller then change the value. and its not working. how do i resolve this ?

`<notif>` tag needed due to css styling *make green color on every flashdata message*

Comment: try to make the redirect with refresh: `redirect('c_material', 'refresh');` if flashing data now works

Comment: @manix still its not working. i don't know what went wrong, since it works on `kategorimaterial` page and not works on `material` page, even though i am using the same syntax

Comment: Strange it doesn't work because going by your code it's the first one that shouldn't work not the second. You have a space after the $this echo statement. Just to be sure it's kategori that works?

Comment: @rick           yes it works on `kategorimaterial` , but, its not working on the material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may advice you to try to track session variable by adding in the view

```
var_dump($this->session);
```

You don't seem to be something wrong but you may try to add this in the controller of material page

```
function index()
{
    $sukses=$this->session->flashdata('sukses');
    if(isset($sukses)
       $data['sukses']=$sukses;
//load your view 
}
```

and in your view of course

```
<div id="vmaterial">
            <p><h2>Menu Material</h2></p>
    <center><notif><?php echo $sukses; ?></notif></center>
```

It's strange issue for sure but you may give this a try and waiting for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

try out to change the 'sukses' key name. flashdata() method is like a stack when you use TOS then it will discard from stack.

Comment: Flashdata key names are reusable.